# How to play secured Youtube url starts with " https://" in ios sdk?

Tags: ios, youtube, streaming

I am working on youtube streaming and displaying youtube thumbnail image.

i used code to display thumbnails:

```
        NSString *Videoidtsr =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[strArray objectAtIndex:i]] ;
        NSLog(@"vidoe sr %@",Videoidtsr);
        NSString *YouTibevideoId=[Videoidtsr bstringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" withString:@""];
        youtubeURLForThumb = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://img.youtube.com/vi/%@/0.jpg",YouTibevideoId]];
        NSLog(@"youtubeURL %@",youtubeURLForThumb);
```

Code for playing youtube video:

```
    - (void)embedYouTube {

videoHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
             <html>\
             <head>\
             <style type=\"text/css\">\
             body {background-color:#000; margin:0;}\
             </style>\
             </head>\
             <body>\
             <iframe width=\"100%%\" height=\"250px\" src=\"\%@\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>\
             </body>\
             </html>", videoURL];

[videoView loadHTMLString:videoHTML baseURL:nil];
```

}

i used url: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FQPJkXyn93c

It wokred fine

but this code is not working for another url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KULJOEkR0l4"

Since it is secured url consists "https"

How to play this type of urls also? and how to create thumbnails? can we paly secured urls in iphone or not?

Any answer can be appreciated.

Please help me in solving this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
NSLog(@"is https scheme ? = %@",[[request URL] scheme]);
//same for if([[[request URL] scheme]isEqualToString:@"http"] ) {
if([[[request URL] scheme]isEqualToString:@"https"] ) {
//here  you call the code / method to play video
return NO;
}
else return YES;
}
```